# How can I register a domain that requires country residency?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

I tried to register a .pm domain from ovh.co.uk, but they e-mailed me saying they want valid proof that I am a resident of the United Kingdom. I currently live in the United States though.

**I am aware that I have to be a resident.** That's not the question I'm asking. I want to know if it's possible, whether through some website that will get residency or some 'hacking' method, to register the domain I am interested in without having to physically be a resident of the country.

I will try and find out if ovh.co.uk will charge me an extra fee, but until then I am curious to know if there is any way I could do this.

Also, is there any other website I could purchase .pm domains from?

Comment: "That's not the question I'm asking." Unless you can provide an alternate definition for "resident" that seems to be *exactly* what you're asking about. That said, Saint Pierre and Miquelon is "a self-governing territorial overseas collectivity of France" so I don't see what **UK** residency has to do with it at all. (Though [this](http://www.ovh.co.uk/domains/dotpm.xml) says EU.) Why don't you ask the [actual registry](http://www.afnic.fr/en/)? I can't seem to find any special requirements or restrictions other than that it's "intended" for entities connected with the territory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site says it can help http://www.101domain.com/pm.htm

> Our trustee service provides the required local contact and any other
>   documentation necessary to register your domain.  If you use this
>   service, you do not need to provide any additional information

Comment: @zzatkin, I'd be cautious about this sort of service, since it's a loophole that the AFNIC might find out and decide to close. If you [read the disclaimer at the bottom](http://www.101domain.com/trustee_service.htm), it doesn't seem to give you many guarantees. You'd also need to check the jurisdiction where your contract applies, should something go wrong. I'm not saying there would be a problem, but it might be wise to read a bit more...

Comment: @Bruno I don't think it's a loophole. It's just a local company offering to register domains for people out of the country. On your own it's pretty easy to get an IBC (international business company) in nearly any country. That meets registrars requirements. Or you can get a mail forwarding address anywhere in the EU and use that to register. There are plenty of ways, going through an already established company be it the one I linked to or any others which offer those services is perfectly fine in my opinion.